# How to use a vertical line in a react project which adjust the height dynamiclly?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

I need to add a vertical line in my react project.I have used scss to create this. But I have given a fixed size there. What I need to do is adjust the height of the line when card size varies. That when I add new comments the card size get increases.But the line height remains same.How can I get the current card size?

This is how it looks like.
[image]

```
 <Col sm={1}>
       <div className="vl"></div>
 </Col>
```

styles.scss

```
.vl {
  border-left: 1px solid $disabled-icons-light-blue;
  height: 800px;
  padding-right: 0px;
}
```

Given below is the file where I have used the line.

```
<div>
        <div className="icon-list">
          <TicketAction icon={<ChevronLeft />} tooltip="Back" />
          <TicketAction icon={<ArrowClockwise />} tooltip="Refresh" />
          <TicketAction icon={<Archive />} tooltip="Archive" />
          <TicketAction icon={<Share />} tooltip="E-mail" />
          <TicketAction icon={<Pencil />} tooltip="Edit" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <Card className="card">
            <Row>
              <Col sm={9}>
                <Card.Body>
                  <div className="header-date text p2">
                    <p2>2 DAYS AGO ON TUESDAY AT 5.43 AM</p2>
                  </div>

                  <Row>
                    <Col sm={3} className="title">
                      <h2>{title}</h2>
                    </Col>
                    <Col sm={7} className="drop-down">
                      <PriorityBadge priority="Error" />
                    </Col>
                    <Col sm={1} style={{paddingLeft: 20}}>
                      <Pencil />
                      &nbsp; Edit
                    </Col>
                  </Row>
                  <div className="ticket-data-topic text p3">
                    <p3>Hello,</p3>
                    <div className="ticket-data-content text p4">
                      <p4
                        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                          __html: description
                        }}
                      ></p4>
                    </div>
                    <hr />
                    <br />
                    <Tabs>
                      <Tab eventKey={1} title="Comments">
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        {this.displayComments()}
                        <br />

                        <h3 className="add-comment-heading">Add Comment</h3>

                        <AddComment ticketID={this.state.id} />
                      </Tab>
                      <Tab
                        eventKey={2}
                        title="History"
                        className="nav-item nav-link active"
                      >
                        History
                      </Tab>
                    </Tabs>
                  </div>
                </Card.Body>
              </Col>
              <Col sm={1}>
                <div className="vl"></div>
              </Col>
              <Col sm={2} className="ticket-data-item-col">
                <Card.Body>
                  <div className=" ticket-item-title text p4">
                    <p>Created by</p>
                  </div>
                  <h4>John Doe (john@gmail.com)</h4>
                  <p className="ticket-data-item">{date}</p>

                  <div className=" ticket-item-title text p4">
                    <p>Ticket ID</p>
                  </div>
                  <h4 className="ticket-data-item">{id}</h4>

                  <div className=" ticket-item-title text p4">
                    <p>Employer</p>
                  </div>
                  <h4 className="ticket-data-item">{employer}</h4>

                  <div className=" ticket-item-title text p4">
                    <p>Assigned to</p>
                  </div>
                  <h4 className="ticket-data-item">{assignee}</h4>

                  <div className=" ticket-item-title text p4">
                    <p>Status</p>
                  </div>
                  <h4 className="ticket-data-item">{status}</h4>

                  <div className=" ticket-item-title text p4">
                    <p>Priority</p>
                  </div>
                  <div className=" ticket-data-item-badge text p4">
                    <PriorityBadge priority={priority} />
                  </div>

                  <div className=" ticket-item-title text p4">
                    <p>Last Updated</p>
                  </div>
                  <h4>John Doe</h4>
                  <p>03/05/2020</p>
                </Card.Body>
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Card>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't set any height:

Use flex or grid to set the layout and don't set

> align-items: 'center'

Then you will be fine the box will grow as your content grow.

For the vertical line use a **border-left** or **border-right**, so that the vertical border will take the height of the Content